# how can I have a rest call without knowing the result class type?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to consume a rest endpoint without knowing the result object type. So basically I did this.

```
 try {

            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

            WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

            ClientResponse response = null;
            if (headerMap.size() > 0) {
                for (String head : headerMap.keySet())

                    response = webResource.accept(contentType)
                        .header(head, headerMap.get(head))
                        .type(contentType)
                        .post(ClientResponse.class, paramMap);
            } else {
                response = webResource.type(contentType).post(
                    ClientResponse.class, paramMap);
            }
....
```

But everytime I make a call I get an error on

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.HashMap, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
```

Checking in other posts seems like there is a wrong parameter, Ive found many similars but dont know how to resolve this one, any idea?

I added this hoping could help as seen in other posts but no luck...

```
@WebServlet(
    urlPatterns = "/",
    initParams = @WebInitParam(name = ">com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", value = "true")
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: REST means HTTP.  You have to transform your Java objects into JSON.

Comment: Thanks! any suggest how to do this?

Comment: Yes, use Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: I already have the dependency, i just dont know how to use it here....

Comment: Map your Java object graph into JSON and POST that.

Comment: The JSON response cannot be mapped to ClientResponse directly (it has no json mapping) as as you don't know the response type (or you don't have the object refined), maybe the best I'd suggest is to return InputStream. Then you could parse it or process further

Comment: Thanks @duffymo I will check how to

Comment: Thanks @gusto2, any idea how to do that?

Comment: What does this have to do with spring? AFAIK you're using jersey, not spring. If you're using spring, use it's rest template or spring integration, not jersey. They're competing technologies, though you'll find docs that says they can work together, they really shouldn't. They belong to different paradigms.

Comment: @EngineerDollery it is based in the first tuto i found